# Test for an instance of angular scope

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I am doing unit testing with the Karma, Mocha, Chai and CoffeeScript stack, and looking to test for a variable being an angular scope.

Something like this would be nice but does not work:

```
 scope = $rootScope.$new()
 expect(scope).to.be.an.instanceOf $rootScope
```

I've already tried all the variants I can think of, includeing `$rootScope::` and `$rootScope.$new()` as arguments for `instanceOf`.

Is there a way to do this?

---

Currently I am going with this:

```
expect(scope.$id).to.exist
```

which is less than ideal.

---

ANSWER:

here is "null"s answer in coffee / mocha / chai

```
 expect(scope.constructor.name).to.equal 'Scope'
```

Comment: What are you trying to assert?  that `scope` is the same type as `rootScope`?

Comment: Just that `scope` is an angular scope. Or rather that `scope` could be considered to have a type of angular scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish but this will be **true** in a *jasmine* test:

```
var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
expect($scope.constructor.name).toBe('Scope');
```

Comment: This only works if you're using the non-.min version on Angular (as .min seems to come back as "h")

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to `$rootScope` then you can do something like this:

```
var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
expect($scope.constructor).toEqual($rootScope.constructor);
```

This also works just fine with minified versions of angular.

If something is not a `Scope` object then you can convert it to one like this:

```
// In this case `context` might be a scope object or just a POJO.
if (context.constructor !== $rootScope.constructor) {
    context = angular.extend($rootScope.$new(), context);
}
```